# Replacing many Words in a .docx File with Powershell

Tags: string, function, powershell, ms-word

I want to replace some Words in my .docx File with some strings from another .txt File via Powershell.
I open and try to replace words with two functions:

```
Function OpenWordDoc($Filename)
{
    $objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
    $objWord.Visible = $True;
    $objWord.Documents.Open($Filename)
    $objSelection = $objWord.Selection
    Return $objSelection; #return objWord
}

Function SearchAWord($Document,$search,$replacewithtext)
{ 
    $FindText = $search 
    $MatchCase = $False 
    $MatchWholeWord = $False 
    $MatchWildcards = $False 
    $MatchSoundsLike = $False 
    $MatchAllWordForms = $False 
    $Forward = $True 
    $Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
    $Format = $False 
    $wdReplaceNone = 1 
    $ReplaceWith = $replacewithtext
    $wdFindContinue = 1 

    $a=$Document.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$wdReplaceNone) 
}
```

When I open the Doc with with the function and try to replace a Word with a string it works, but when I try to change more Words it does not find other Words with the function.
I can find them when I search for them directly after opening the doc. So the script allways only finds the first word searched.

Did I create the functions wrong?

Edit: I'm calling the functions like this:

```
$doc=OpenWordDoc -Filename "C:\Users\$UserName\Desktop\test.docx"; #opens the Word-doc
for([int]$i=0; $i -ne 4;$i++)
{
  SearchAWord -Document $doc -search "string$i" -replacewithtext "test$i"
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `SearchAWord` could you add this code?

Comment: @Richard added the calls to both functions in main-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer:

When you want to replace more than one string in the Doc you have to change the value of the last `Replace` variable in the `$Document.Find.Execute` methode to `2`, this sets the function `WdReplace-Constant` to `"replace all"`:

```
$Document.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord,$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,2)
```